# SharePoint Multilines of text field with JavaScript

Tags: rest, multiline-text-field

I have a SharePoint multilines of text field, where I add line breaks (Enter), when I render the value using REST and add it to an html element, it's not rendered with the line breaks, although I am using $("#idOfField").html(multinesText);

where multilinesText is the value returned by my field.

It looks like this in browser console:

> this requirement is as follows: ↵↵1- documenA ↵2- documentB

Any idea?

Comment: what is the actual value of multinesText coming from REST api response, you might have to replace "\n" with </br> in multinesText variable..

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data response into temp object and then do then do the string replacement. See the multiline function described in the StackOverFlow post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535888/jquery-text-and-newlines